# Scala 2.9.2 can not handle the overloaded format method of the String class - why?

Tags: java, scala, overloading

Example:

```
scala> String.format("%d", 2)
<console>:8: error: overloaded method value format with alternatives:
  (java.util.Locale,java.lang.String,<repeated...>[java.lang.Object])java.lang.String <and>
  (java.lang.String,<repeated...>[java.lang.Object])java.lang.String
 cannot be applied to (java.lang.String, Int)
              String.format("%d", 2)
                     ^
```

Why can Scala not handle the overloaded `format` method of the `String` class ?

Using: Scala 2.9.2 on Windows 7 64 Bit.

Answer (score 15):

Use this instead:

```
"%d".format(2)
```

The `String.format` method is a Java thing, so it's expecting input parameters that are subtypes of `java.lang.Object`.  Scala's `Int` is not a `java.lang.Object`:

```
scala> val i: java.lang.Object = 2
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(2)
 required: java.lang.Object
Note: an implicit exists from scala.Int => java.lang.Integer, but
methods inherited from Object are rendered ambiguous.  This is to avoid
a blanket implicit which would convert any scala.Int to any AnyRef.
You may wish to use a type ascription: `x: java.lang.Integer`.
       val i: java.lang.Object = 2
                                 ^
```

To learn more about this, you should read up on Scala's distinction between `AnyVal` and `AnyRef` types.  Java has a distinction between objects (like `Integer`) and primitives (like `int`), for efficiency.  Scala has a similar distinction.  All types extend from `Any`, but "value types" (basically corresponding to primitives) extend from `AnyVal` and everything else extends from `AnyRef` (basically `java.lang.Object`).  Read more [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/128).

So, to use `String.format` you'd have to replace it with a Java `Integer`, which is an `Object`:

```
String.format("%d", new java.lang.Integer(2))
```

But don't do this; just use it the Scala way, as mentioned above.

Comment: what is so special about Int?

Comment: Thank you. But shouldn't Scala do an automatically conversion here ? E.g. method `String.valueOf(i)` works fine with `val i: Int = 2`.

Comment: Thank you for extending your answer, that helped. But now I am wondering, why Scala's Int is not a subtype of Java's Object. I always thought all classes (Scala and Java) are subtypes of the Object class ?

Comment: @John, I added a bit about which things are not Objects

Comment: @dhg Alright, I see, thank you. So even the fact that all classes (including Scala's Int) are subtypes from the Object class, there is no implicit conversion of Int to Object, because of the distinction of AnyVal and AnyRef (which comes from Java as you wrote). Is my understading correct ?

Comment: @John, Mostly, except that `Int` isn't a subtype of Object because it's sort of like a primitive.  Everything is a subtype of `Any`.  Only some things are subtypes of `AnyRef` (non-primitive-like things).  And `AnyRef` is the same as `java.lang.Object`.

Answer (score 2):

The first overloaded definition can't match because the first argument is `Locale`, while you provided a String.

The second alternative can't match because the second argument is a vararg parameter of `Object`, but you provided `Int`. `Int` is not a subtype of `Object` (called `AnyRef` in Scala). Java "fixes" it by auto-boxing, but in the Scala type-system there is no automatic conversion from the primitive type `Int` to `java.lang.Integer`.

If the Java definition was generic, something like `format[T](f: String, args: T*)`, Scala would allow your call, because unbounded type parameters in Scala range over primitive types as well.